# Detect if Device is in Daydream VR Headset

Tags: google-vr

How can I detect if the device is in the Daydream headset? 
In particular, is this API function exposed in the Unity SDK?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of just asking 'How do I do this?', please post what you've tried so far and hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem ([link](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/detect-if-daydream-vr-headset-is-on.441469/)) you can't detect if the device is in the Daydream headset.. As of February 2017 this still appears to be true.